# Was Picasso inspired by physics?

Tags: art

Was Picasso inspired by the back then new fourth dimension of space? A 3D observer in 2D space can see a 2D object in its entirety. It is assumed that a 4D perspective can do the same for 3D objects. In Picasso's paintings we can see frequently faces that are seen from various directions at once.

Was he curious about 4D space?

Comment: This seems to be a question about history of art rather than history of science.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You would think so indeed. I thought this myself. But it asks about the history of 4d space. If it influenced art. Not about how it came to be.

Answer (score 1):

> Pablo Picasso not only looked at the projections of four-dimensional
> cubes in a mathematics book when he invented cubism, he also read the
> text, embracing not just the images but also the ideas.

Tony Robbin, *Shadows of Reality The Fourth Dimension in
Relativity, Cubism, and Modern Thought*, Yale UP 2006. (pref. p.X)

Comment: I knew about the cubism ( I should have mentioned). But are his other paintings influenced by this? Women with two noses or seen from two sides at once?

Comment: Well, I guess that during his "African Period" he was not much influenced by 4D theories, but perhaps you are asking about something else.

Comment: I didnt know about his African perioď. I mean for example the 1932 painting "Young girl in front of a mirror".